# Not able use sforce.one.editrecord() in Java script

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am using EditRecord java script navigation method.But this is not working for me. I am getting error in Inspect elements.
Illegal literal.

I used this way
Function redirect(){
sforce.one.editrecord('{!id}');

I am getting error in while accessing Id in editrecord javascript in bulit function.

Please help me.